# How does pandas concat function do column joins without specify common key?

Tags: python, pandas, join

Greetings to my dear fellow Pythoners!

Today, when I was going through a Python course on data camp, a simple data join with pd.concat() really stood up to me. I couldn't seem to understand the logic behind the join. I need your help!

Consider the following case which is a simplified version, and we want to use pd.concat() to join this two table:

Table A:

```
Date        Day        status_country        counts
1/5/2015    289        Cases_Guinea          2776.0
1/4/2015    288        Cases_Guinea          2775.0
1/3/2015    287        Cases_Guinea          2769.0
1/2/2015    286        Cases_Guinea             NaN
12/31/2015  284        Cases_Guinea          2730.0
```

Table B:

```
status    country
 Cases     Guinea
 Cases     Guinea
 Cases     Guinea
 Cases     Guinea
 Cases     Guinea
```

Python code:

```
pd.concat([ebola_melt, status_country], axis = 1)
```

Return Data:

```
Date        Day        status_country        counts    status    country
1/5/2015    289        Cases_Guinea          2776.0     Cases     Guinea
1/4/2015    288        Cases_Guinea          2775.0     Cases     Guinea
1/3/2015    287        Cases_Guinea          2769.0     Cases     Guinea
1/2/2015    286        Cases_Guinea             NaN     Cases     Guinea
12/31/2015  284        Cases_Guinea          2730.0     Cases     Guinea
```

***Question:***

Obviously, there is no common index between this two tables unless you parse 'status_country' column in table A and then match it to table B, but I am not sure if this function is smart enough to do that.

What kind of matching logic is behind this function?

Is it doing partial matching or parse then match?

How would I understand it?

Comment: It's doing nothing, all it did was to add your table B to the right of table A, because you specified `axis=1`

Comment: It's joining based on index, which you have not included in the question. Likely these two `DataFrames` have a simple `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=len(df), step=1)`

Comment: @RockyLi That explains it! It was a simple row-wise concatenation without finding a common index in the column value. Initially, I thought the pd.concat() algorithm could identify the match between "Cases_Guinea" with ["Cases", "Guinea"]

Answer (score 2):

`pd.concat` is base on the `index`

For example you have

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4]},index=[2,3,4,5])
```

When you do `concat` , you are doing `join` by index , or `merge` by index

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
Out[303]: 
     A    A
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN
2  3.0  1.0
3  4.0  2.0
4  NaN  3.0
5  NaN  4.0
```

Comment: Thanks, Wen! Given it's solely based on the row index with this concatenation, the result will be incorrect if the order of the data was wrong. That makes sense.

Comment: @smzsmzsmz glad I can help